# Add a list of times in php

Tags: php, time

I'm working on something where I need to add a list of times togther in the following format mm:ss so 3:10 would be 3 minutes and 10 seconds.

So how for example would you go about the following sum in php?

```
2:10 + 3:15 + 6:59 + 2:22
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Convert all the times to a number of seconds, do your sum, convert back to the expected format.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't as of yet. I just wondered if there was a standard way people went about this sort of sum. I am a relative beginner and the help this community usually provide is amazingly clear, consice and easy to wrap my head around. Sorry if this question is out of place.

Comment: As software developers, our job is to *think* of solutions. We are not paid to find them (although sometimes that's the faster route, as others have thought of the best answers already). However, for something this elementary, you should be thinking of your own solutions, then trying to find if someone has found a better/more efficient solution.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll be sure to at least have attempted a solution of my own before posting next time.

Comment: @alfasin it was me; I flagged them as off-topic / chatty.

Comment: @alfasin, they disappeared immediately after I flagged them; ::shrug:: didn't mean to be a jerk, it's just that those comments don't help OP find a solution.

Comment: @alfasin *"What have you tried?"* helps me to understand what *isn't* working, so I can suggest an alternative solution; my second comment was sort of a scolding, and I'll remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following code :

```
$tarr = array('2:10', '3:15','6:59','2:22');
echo sum_the_time($tarr);  

function sum_the_time($times) {
  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
  //  $seconds += $second;
  }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds); 
}
```

Here is the demo : http://codepad.org/dJBY78wZ

Comment: Thanks! this worked great with a couple of small tweaks.

Also, after some advice from Matt, I've realised I should at least be trying a solution of my own before posting here, so my apologies for that. I really appreciate this communities continued patience and support :p

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun :)

```
function sumTime($times) {
    $min = $sec = 0;
    foreach($times as $time) {
        list($cmin, $csec) = explode(':', $time);
        $min += $cmin;
        $sec += $csec;
    }
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $min + floor($sec/60), $sec % 60);
}
```

http://viper-7.com/txkHAs

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function s($str) {
  list($minutes,$seconds) = explode(':',$str);
  return $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}    
function ms($seconds) {
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d', $seconds/60, $seconds%60);
}    

$seconds = s('2:10') + s('3:15') + s('6:59') + s('2:22');    
echo ms($seconds);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/BUkRRM